# Microsoft word 2010 open file in new window

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

The word program in my computer (Windows 7) doesn't work properly. If I open several files at the same time files are opened in one window.
How to change settings of microsoft word 2010 so that every file is opened in a new window?

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the [answer on microsoft.com](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/Manage-multiple-windows). I hate this feature, too.

> If you don't want to group taskbar buttons, you can turn off grouping. But without grouping, you might not be able to see all of your taskbar buttons at once.
>
> To stop grouping similar taskbar buttons on the taskbar:
>
> - Open Taskbar and Start Menu Properties by clicking the Start button, clicking Control Panel, clicking Personalization, and then clicking Taskbar and Start Menu.
> - On the Taskbar tab, under Taskbar appearance, select "Never combine from the Taskbar buttons menu", and then click OK.